# <input message ant displays the input entered

Tags: java, ant

i want to take input password through ant, i tried using `<input message` but it displays the character/password entered.

Instead of displaying the characters entered i want to display the '*' character can anybody tell me how it is possible.

Thanks,
rbhawsar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ant 1.8 you can specify an additional `<handler/>` tag inside of the `<input/>` tag with type "secure":

```
<target name="test.input">
  <input message="Type password:" addproperty="pwd">
    <handler type="secure" />
  </input>
  <echo message="Password is: ${pwd}" />
</target>
```

See the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html). It is even possible to write your own input handler class.

I tested it inside a Windows DOS box and it worked. But it failed to work inside  a cygwin xterm session (the characters are shown).